# A complex minimization problem

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, optimization

Let $M_a(\mathbb{C})$ the space of all symmetric (w.r.t conjugation) probability measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that the support of $\mu$ is included in $R_a:=\{z\in\mathbb{C};\ \Re(z)\leq a\}$, and where $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Define:
\begin{equation}
I(\mu):=\int_{\mathbb{C}}|z|^2\mu(dz)-\int_{\mathbb{C}}\int_{\mathbb{C}} \ln|z-z'|\mu(dz)\mu(dz')
\end{equation}
The problem is the following :
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Find  }\Theta(a)=\displaystyle{\inf_{\mu \in M_a(\mathbb{C})}} I(\mu)
\end{equation}

What I know is that when $a\geq 1$, then the minimizer is the uniform density on the disk of radius 1, and I am interested in what happens for $a<1$.

Thank you for your help!